# Scan current folder using PHP

Tags: php, filesystems, directory

I have a folder structure like this:

```
/articles
     .index.php
     .second.php
     .third.php
     .fourth.php
```

If I'm writing my code in second.php, how can I scan the current folder(articles)?

Thanks

Comment: just a note: in something like `scandir('.')` the period refers to the current directory

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$files = glob(dirname(__FILE__) . "/*.php");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach (scandir('.') as $file)
    echo $file . "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

From the PHP [manual](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php):

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname($path));
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        var_dump($fileinfo->getFilename());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$path = new DirectoryIterator('/articles');

foreach ($path as $file) {
    echo $file->getFilename() . "\t";
    echo $file->getSize() . "\t";
    echo $file->getOwner() . "\t";
    echo $file->getMTime() . "\n";
}

?>
```

[From The Standard PHP Library (SPL)](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2565#section3-2)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by 'scan' I'm assuming you want to do something like this:

```
$dir_handle = opendir(".");

 while($file = readdir($dir_handle)){
      //do stuff with $file
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   $dir = glob(dirname(__FILE__));
   $directory = array_diff(scandir($dir[0]), array('..', '.'));
   print_r($directory);
```

Answer (score 0):

Scan current folder

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$x = $zip->open($filepath);
if ($x === true) {
  $zip->extractTo($uploadPath); // place in the directory
  $zip->close();

  $fileArray = scandir($uploadPath);
    unlink($filepath);
}
 foreach ($fileArray as $file) {
    if ('.' === $file || '..' === $file) 
    continue;
    if (!is_dir("$file")){
       //do stuff with $file
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List all images inside a folder

```
$dir = glob(dirname(__FILE__));

$path = $dir[0].'\\images';

$imagePaths = array_diff( scandir( $path ), array('.', '..', 'Thumbs.db')); 
?>
<ul style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 80vh;">
<?php

    foreach($imagePaths as $imagePath)
    {
?>
    <li><?php echo '<img class="pagina" src="images/'.$imagePath.'" />'; ?></li>
<?php
    }
        ?>
</ul>
```