# Best way to get files from a dir filtered by certain extension in php

Tags: php, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP list of specific files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062154/php-list-of-specific-files-in-a-directory)
>   [use php scandir($dir) and get only images!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226519/use-php-scandirdir-and-get-only-images)

So right now I have a directory and I am getting a list of files

```
$dir_f = "whatever/random/";
$files = scandir($dir_f);
```

That, however, retrieves every file in a directory. How would I retrive only files with a certain extension such as .ini in most efficient way.

Comment: There is like a couple dozen question asking the same. [Please do research before asking questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice)

Comment: Use [`scandir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Comment: `//path to directory to scan
$directory = "../file/";`
 
`//get all image files with a .text extension.`
`$images = glob($directory . "*.text ");`
 
`//print each file name`
`foreach($images as $image)`
`{`
`echo $image;`
`}`

Comment: I think that [`glob`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) would be a better choice than `scandir`.

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php `glob("*.txt")`

Answer (score 117, accepted):

PHP has a great function to help you capture only the files you need. Its called `glob()`

> **glob** - Find pathnames matching a pattern

> Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error.

Here is an example usage -

```
$files = glob("/path/to/folder/*.txt");
```

This will populate the `$files` variable with a list of all files matching the `*.txt` pattern in the given path.

Reference -

- [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: please do not answer obvious duplicates but closevote them. thanks.

Comment: @gor - needed more than just my vote to close as a [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646099/scan-current-folder-using-php)...

Comment: @Lix why not to use `$files = glob("/path/to/folder/*.txt")` directly without `for` ?. I think it's the same

Comment: @MohamadOsama - You're absolutely right :) Always fun to look back 8 years at my old code haha! Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Lix - Yes it's very old code but these help me fix my problem nowadays. you are welcome Bro.

Answer (score 22):

If you want more than one extension searched, then [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep) is an alternative for filtering:

```
 $files = preg_grep('~\.(jpeg|jpg|png)$~', scandir($dir_f));
```

Though `glob` has a similar extra syntax. This mostly makes sense if you have further conditions, add the `~i` flag for case-insensitive, or can filter combined lists.

Comment: `glob("{$dir}*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,ico,png}", GLOB_BRACE)`. This would work as well for multiple extensions.

Comment: This answer was extremely helpful for me! I was trying to search for hundreds of different file identifiers and files in a folder with tens to hundreds of thousands of files. glob couldn't handle such a big search string, and if I broke into into smaller strings and looped it took several minutes. using preg_grep with scandir takes about 5 seconds!

Comment: Thanks for introducing preg_grep to me. This is much more helpful as compared to glob it can handle case insensitives.

Comment: This works with square brackets in the path, while square brackets using glob() have to be escaped.

Answer (score 9):

PHP's [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function let's you specify a pattern to search for.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using `GlobIterator`

```
$iterator = new \GlobIterator(__DIR__ . '/*.txt', FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_FILENAME);
$array = iterator_to_array($iterator);
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

[glob($pattern, $flags)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
//path to directory to scan
$directory = "../file/";

//get all image files with a .txt extension.
$file= glob($directory . "*.txt ");

//print each file name
foreach($file as $filew)
{
echo $filew;
$files[] = $filew; // to create the array

}
```

Comment: I don't know any files with a `.text` extension.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha sorry it was a typo

Comment: there could be files with any extension

Answer (score 2):

haven't tested the regex but something like this:

```
if ($handle = opendir('/file/path')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if (preg_match('/\.txt$/', $entry)) {
            echo "$entry\n";
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```