# Best Way to Retrieve File Names in a Directory with a Specified Extension in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file, list, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to get files from a dir filtered by certain extension in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541180/best-way-to-get-files-from-a-dir-filtered-by-certain-extension-in-php)

What would be the best way to retrieve file names with a specified extension?

I came up with this solution and it works fine but am wondering if there is a better way.

```
print_r(array_filter(scandir(dirname(__FILE__)), create_function('$a', 'return (substr($a, -4) == ".php") ? true : false ;')));
```

Comment: Better in what way? Did you run some Unit Tests?

Comment: I'm expecting a better way in readability and efficiency. What does unit test mean?

Comment: Teno, it's used with Test Driven Development (TDD). By writing tests you, find out of your code is doing it's job. http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/automating-tests.html

Comment: I see thanks. I don't understand why this question got a down vote as complex857 showed a better solution. It's an important question.

Comment: Sometimes a question looking like a duplicate can result on conveying another perspective. So what's wrong with it. We get better information then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). Maybe the most simplistic approach to this:

```
$files = glob( dirname(__FILE__) . '/*.php'); 
$files = array_map('basename', $files);
print_r($files);
```

Comment: That's better, simple and easy to understand. I was expecting something like this.

Comment: If the file pattern contains a directory path, the retrieved paths becomes file paths as well. How could it be improved to retrieve only file names?

Comment: @Teno `array_map('basename', $files)`

Comment: One problem with it that we cannot pass a parameter to the function, basename. Otherwise, all fine.