# Get all files in directory with specified extension with PHP?

Tags: php, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to get files from a dir filtered by certain extension in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541180/best-way-to-get-files-from-a-dir-filtered-by-certain-extension-in-php)

I would like to create an array of the filenames of all .txt files in my directory.

Directory contents:
 - file1.txt
 - file2.txt
 - otherfile.php

Example array:
 - files[1]file1.txt
 - files[2]file2.txt