# Make a menu with the names of the files in a directory

Tags: php, html, menu, directory

I want to make a small extra menu for my website. Is it possible to get the name of the files in a directory and put them in the menu.

So if you have a directory with files: facebook.php; twitter.php; stackoverflow.html; that you will get a menu like this:

- facebook
- twitter
- stackoverflow

And if it's possible I want to choose that what kind of files he gets. So I want him to get the name of .php and .html files but not of .css files.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: This question has been asked before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541180/best-way-to-get-files-from-a-dir-filtered-by-certain-extension-in-php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like glob():

```
foreach(glob("$dir/{*.php,*.html}", GLOB_BRACE) as $file) {
    //whatever
}
```

or

```
$files = glob("$dir/{*.php,*.html}", GLOB_BRACE); //then use $files wherever
```

You can use pathinfo() with PATHINFO_BASENAME to get only filename PATHINFO_FILENAME to get it without the extension.

Comment: Now i know how to get the file names, but do you also know how i can put each filename in a other li? I'm not really good with php but I want to learn it.

Comment: @Moreno__R: In the first example just replace //whatever with `echo "<li>".pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME)."</li>";`

Answer (score 0):

Try the [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) method

In the loop check the current file is a directory with is_dir(). And then you can get the path with [dirname]/[dirname.php]. Check if an exist file, and then you can display the link.

```
$files = scandir('menus');
$links = array();
foreach ($files as $file) {
   if ($file == "." || $file == "..")
      continue;

   if (is_dir($file)) {
      $menuFile = "./menus/$file/$file.php";
      if (is_file($menuFile)) {
         $links[$file] = $menuFile;
      }
   }
}

//display the links
```